# Why do I get a warning "Assigning 'void' from a function reset()" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have written a class where one method is used to extract the vintage year from a wine's product name:

```
private function parse_vintage($prodname) {
    // Try to find the vintage in the product name "NNNN NNNN 2018 (winetype)" (e.g. "Chateau Petrus 2001 (Red)")
    $words = explode(' ', $prodname);
    $vintages = preg_grep("/(19|20)[0-9]{2}/", $words); 
    $vintage = reset($vintages);
    return ($vintage ? $vintage : "");
}
```

The function works fine. But in my code editor (Visual Studio Code) I get a coding warning stating that says `Assigning "void" from a function reset()`. See image below:

[image]

If I copy the method to another file and the warning disappears. Why do I get this warning... and only in this and similar contexts? As far as I know, the `reset()` function is not a void function... Is it something wrong with any of my Extensions? (BTW I use Devsense's PHP extension and some other as well...)

Comment: @brettkelly Oh, I am not really sure how I solved this. I found the code in my project and it seems that I simply added a type conversion to force it to be a string, i.e. `$vintage = (string)reset($vintages)`